# This error where add frappe erpnext after bench update

Tags: python, erpnext, frappe

after some changing in ERPNext, update the bench by suing command

```
bench update --reset
bench migrate
bench clear-cache
```

but face error

then try to update config file but error still appear after login to site. how to resolve this issue, please help

```
sudo nano /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf
chown=frappe:frappe
```

Loged in but not facing mention error.

```
Uncaught Server Exception

There was an error building this page

Home

Error Code: 500

Hide Traceback

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "apps/frappe/frappe/www/app.py", line 28, in get_context
    boot = frappe.sessions.get()
  File "apps/frappe/frappe/sessions.py", line 158, in get
    bootinfo = get_bootinfo()
  File "apps/frappe/frappe/boot.py", line 39, in get_bootinfo
    get_user(bootinfo)
  File "apps/frappe/frappe/boot.py", line 282, in get_user
    bootinfo.user = frappe.get_user().load_user()
  File "apps/frappe/frappe/utils/user.py", line 210, in load_user
    d = frappe.db.get_value(
  File "apps/frappe/frappe/database/database.py", line 509, in get_value
    result = self.get_values(
  File "apps/frappe/frappe/database/database.py", line 606, in get_values
    out = self._get_values_from_table(
  File "apps/frappe/frappe/database/database.py", line 835, in _get_values_from_table
    return query.run(as_dict=as_dict, debug=debug, update=update, run=run, pluck=pluck)
  File "apps/frappe/frappe/query_builder/utils.py", line 87, in execute_query
    result = frappe.db.sql(query, params, *args, **kwargs)  # nosemgrep
  File "apps/frappe/frappe/database/database.py", line 220, in sql
    self._cursor.execute(query, values)
  File "env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 158, in execute
    result = self._query(query)
  File "env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 325, in _query
    conn.query(q)
  File "env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 549, in query
    self._affected_rows = self._read_query_result(unbuffered=unbuffered)
  File "env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 779, in _read_query_result
    result.read()
  File "env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 1157, in read
    first_packet = self.connection._read_packet()
  File "env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 729, in _read_packet
    packet.raise_for_error()
  File "env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pymysql/protocol.py", line 221, in raise_for_error
    err.raise_mysql_exception(self._data)
  File "env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pymysql/err.py", line 143, in raise_mysql_exception
    raise errorclass(errno, errval)
pymysql.err.OperationalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'onboarding_status' in 'field list'")

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "apps/frappe/frappe/website/serve.py", line 18, in get_response
    response = renderer_instance.render()
  File "apps/frappe/frappe/website/page_renderers/template_page.py", line 84, in render
    html = self.get_html()
  File "apps/frappe/frappe/website/utils.py", line 517, in cache_html_decorator
    html = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "apps/frappe/frappe/website/page_renderers/template_page.py", line 95, in get_html
    self.update_context()
  File "apps/frappe/frappe/website/page_renderers/template_page.py", line 162, in update_context
    data = self.run_pymodule_method("get_context")
  File "apps/frappe/frappe/website/page_renderers/template_page.py", line 224, in run_pymodule_method
    return method(self.context)
  File "apps/frappe/frappe/www/app.py", line 30, in get_context
    raise frappe.SessionBootFailed from e
frappe.exceptions.SessionBootFailed
```

this code if facing after

```
bench update --reset
bench migrate
bench clear-cache
```

I try

```
chmod -R o+rx /home/frappe
sudo nano /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf

chmod=0755
chmod=0760
chown=frappe:frappe
```

and then try bench update,

but facing same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error has been resolved
after try

```
bench --site frappe.com migrate
```